# Local area connection (WLAN) between android device and laptop via Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, wamp

I'm a newbie to android and a student.I'm working with WAMP (host_server) and android devices(Client). My connection setup is done by Microsoft virtual adapter for hotspot on laptop and DHCP server assigning IP to clients. Everything works correctly. Mobile devices are connected to the hotspot.

In Wamp server's HTTPd.conf "Require all granted" written. Windows firewall rule created for port 8080. Wamp server index page is accessed by typing IP of my laptop in the mobile browser.

The problem is the WAMP server's index page is accessed by all devices but one device is causing the problem. That device has kit kat version android OS. It connects to the wifi (my laptop) and IP is assigned to it. But wamp server page is not coming. All other devices in the Wifi connection can able to show the wamp server page. I tried "ping IP (of that kit kat version android mobile)" in cmd and resulted in request timed out. Other connected devices got reply packets in cmd. The problem is on the kit kat version mobile. I don't think OS causes the problem.

Something is doing the problem in device wifi local area connection. Can anybody help how to trace the problem in the particular device? That device works and connects to host(laptop) whenever connected via another mobile's hotspot(lap also connected in that mobile's hotspot) but I don't know why it's not working(WLAN) when directly connected to laptop's hotspot. The problem is 100% with mobile side.Can Anybody help me?